# Community standards for written English in comments and answers

Tags: discussion

I'm a newbie here and so have many questions, some of which I can't seem to find answers to in the FAQ or by using Search or by any other means. This is one of those. I mention my newbie status also to support the fact that this is an actual question and not a veiled criticism from someone who already knows the answer. (Yes, maybe I'm a little paranoid.)

Is it the community standard and/or for some other reason acceptable or expected that comments and less frequently answers posted to English Language and Usage lack capitalization and/or ignore other standards of written English which this site seems intended to clarify and support? Or do such comments and answers most likely contain typos or other unintended mistakes?

I realize users can't say for sure what is true in every such individual example here, but I figure you can still answer my question.

Comment: Wrong Meta, [you want to go over there](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/), because we're all crazy here.

Answer (score 3):

Questions and answers can be edited for usage at any time by (almost) anyone, while comments can only be edited for five minutes by the author. Unless particularly egregious, many minor errors simply stand.

Answer (score 2):

Questions and answers posted on any SE site where English is the language used for posts are supposed to follow the English standards, which include to capitalize the *I* in phrases like *I think that it is not true*.
This is not expected to happen in comments, where you could write *i think that is not true*. I mean, you can still follow the English standards in comments, but I don't expect that standards are strictly followed in comments.
About questions titles, the title for questions on Stack Exchange sites normally uses the sentence case, not the title case.

To notice that in some cases the standards change basing on the English dialect: American English writes the dates differently from British English (e.g. *November 13, 2010*, instead of *13 November 2010*). In an SE site you could use one of the standards that are used in a specific English dialect; there isn't a specific standard that has been used.

There are sites that allow question in two different languages, or in a language that is not English. In those cases, the standards are not necessarily the English ones, when the post is not written in English.

Comment: i take issue with non-capitalized I's, even in comments. The only reason you see any is because I haven't got edit rights on other people's comments! (And also quite possibly because of people's @s getting eaten)

Comment: (And yes, that was deliberate)

Comment: Only moderators can edit every comment, and I am sure they don't use that privilege for editing all the i's in I's.